# In Azure media service, can I delete the original uploaded video once I have my processed videos?

Tags: azure, azure-media-services

Anyone has idea about this? 
In Azure media service: I first upload a video (asset A). Then I create jobs to process it and get encoded video (asset B). Since asset A normally is much larger than asset B, can I delete asset A to save some space? (of course I have local copy of the original video, so if needed, I can upload again)

The reason I am asking is that I heard Azure treat these assets with parent-child relationships. So I don't want to mess up something there ....

Thanks!

Comment: Does the answer help you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, if the video processing is done, you can safely delete the original video.

Cheers,
Mingfei Yan

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can safely delete asset A in this case.

There is no parent-child relationships between the raw video and processed videos based on the raw video which you assume.

I have tested your scenario with my Azure mobile service account and the processed contents are not affected when I deleted the original content.